# Почему «Директор зоопарка», но «Заведующий зоопарком»?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

Почему «Директор зоопарка», но **«Заведующий зоопарком»**?

«Заведующий» здесь не существительное?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start from the beginning.

1. The verb `заведовать` means `to manage`, `to supervise`. (Below I'll translate it as `to supervise`.) This verb, along with similar verbs (`руководить`, `управлять`, `править`, `командовать`), governs instrumental case: `руководить предприятием`, `управлять государством`, `командовать армией`, `заведовать складом`.
2. `Заведующий` is a participle (причастие) made from this verb.  In Russian, participles govern the same cases as their respective verbs. So, `заведующий` also governs instrumental case: `заведовать зоопарком` -> `заведующий зоопарком`.
3. Thе noun phrase `заведующий зоопарком` should be translated, most literally, as `one who supervises the zoo`.
4. In this noun phrase, `заведующий` is a "substantiated participle". In simple terms, it means the participle is now "working as a noun". That is not important for our purposes. The word `заведующий` still governs instrumental case, no matter what. Semantically, it is a noun in this expression, but grammatically, it remains a participle.
5. Similarly, for example, if a profession "любящий зоопарк" existed, the word `зоопарк` would be in accusative, because the verb `любить` governs accusative.
6. What about the word `директор`? There is no story behing it. It is just a boring, plain noun. As any noun, it governs genitive.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent! You have actually explained how it works. I am surprised that it was not possible for ordinary speakers to explain it. I now speculate that they actually remember such combinations by heart.

Comment: @rapt i think the fact of learning native language by heart is true for native speakers of any language, very few people try to rationalize, by the time children go to school they're already pretty proficient and after graduation the majority forget the rules they've learned

Comment: A very good answer. Along with the suggested literal translation, a version grammatically close to the Russian Instrumental Case (зоопарком) might be useful for even better understanding: the one _dealing with_ the Zoo('s everyday problems).

Comment: and another analogy, if one translates ***заведовать*** as ***to watch over*** then ***заведующий + Instrumental*** would correspond to the ***watcher OVER*** *smth*, in which the preposition *over* is still required just like the Instrumental for *заведовать*

Answer (score 5):

[Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9) утверждает, что "заведующий" - это, в частности, существительное. Так же, как "[управляющий](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9)".
Но очевидно, что это субстантивированные причастия, и с дополнением их принято согласовывать по модели причастий.

Опять же, в Wiktionary примеры предложений с этими словами содержат именно такой тип согласования.

И [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC) это подтверждает

> Правильно: *заместитель управляющего **отделением***.
>   Правильно: *работает в должности заведующего терапевтическим
>
>   **отделением***.
>   Слово заведующий управляет творительным падежом.

---

### [Субстантивированное причастие](http://pedlib.ru/Books/4/0038/4_0038-131.shtml)

> § 99. Переход причастий в прилагательные и существительные
>
> Причастия могут употребляться также **в значении имени существительного**, т.е. **субстантивироваться.** Ср.: Поле, окружающее деревню. — Окружающее его утомляло. В предложении
>   субстантивированные причастия являются подлежащим или дополнением:
>   Минувшее проходит предо мною. (П.) Мересьев устал от всего пережитого.
>   (Б. Пол.)

<sup>*Борисоглебская Э.И., Гурченкова В.П., Курбыко А.Е. и др. Русский язык: Пособие для поступающих в вузы*</sup>

### [Субстантива́ция, или субстантиви́рование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> (от лат. substantivum — существительное), — **переход в разряд имён
>   существительных** других частей речи (прилагательных, глаголов,
>   **причастий**, числительных), вследствие приобретения ими способности непосредственно указывать на предмет.
>
> - причастие: «командующий отдал приказ»

<sup>*Wikipedia*</sup>

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему это так. Я не вижу здесь объяснений, только подтверждение того, что это так. Maybe you could elaborate - What is the closest English equivalent, and/or closest literal English translation of such expressions as "Заведующий зоопарком"? Not clear what you mean by "субстантивированные причастия", and why that should make it all obvious to me. I had actually asked about it some native speakers, who are not linguists, before posting it here. They either could only say that it sounds correct, or at best they gave some hand-waving but could not explain.

Comment: Я всегда считал что в словосочетании "заведующий зоопарком" первое слово - это причастие, а существительным оно становится только без зависимого слова. И на Wiktionary вообще-то указаны оба варианта классификации.

Comment: @rapt do you want me to rewrite the answer in English?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov можно попросить вас предоставить ссылку на Wiktionary, где указаны оба варианта классификации? я вижу только как существительное по обоим указанным в ответе адресам, причём очень крупным шрифтом

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка у нас с вами разные Wikitionary? Вот что вижу я по первой из ваших же ссылок: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQdH9.png

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov спасибо, я на это не обратил внимания, потому что оно неактуально для ответа на вопрос, т.к. в том смысле и грамматической роли, в которых слово употреблено в вопросе, оно соответствует статье о существительном, что подтверждается приведёнными в ней примерами и толкованием, но я подкорректировал ответ, добавив оговорку

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка No. I mean, could you literally translate into English the two expressions that I juxtaposed in the title, in a way that would clearly show the reasoning behind not constructing "Заведующий зоопарком" as a possessive form (Genitive case)? To me "Заведующий зоопарком" looks something like "the manager with the zoo" (while "Директор зоопарка" is simply " the manager of the zoo"). Is it how native speakers see it? I think it would be better to focus on how native speakers who are not linguists view the difference between the two types of constructs.

Comment: @rapt, заведовать - to manage, to supervise. Заведующий - тот, кто заведует - one who is managing/supervising. Заведующий зоопарком - тот, кто заведует зоопарком - one who is managing/supervising the zoo.  The verb заведовать governs instrumental case (заведовать чем-то). Therefore, the participle заведующий also governs instrumental vase.

Comment: @rapt i guess user31264 has already explained it to your satisfaction, but i don't think it can be literally translated into English due to insufficiency of English grammatical apparatus in this particular case, his translation is rather an interpretation, explanation through the corresponding verb case governance is in my opinion the most apt, but the fact of your unfamiliarity with this (obvious to myself) detail wasn't clear from the original question